# Cómo convertir una variable text a int y sacar suma total? en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una super duda en que debo sumar el valor total de personas que adquieren el servicio en el día, dependiendo el servicio que se contrata (habitaciones), pero los campos son frases string y entre ellas son diferentes, les dejo la muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, la "**Habitación 1 persona**" debería ser el valor **1**, "**Habitación 2 personas**" valor **2**, "**Habitación 2 personas full**" también **2**, el último valor de cada condición indica el número de personas que asiste por día; la idea es tener ese desglose para poder realizar un tipo SUM o COUNT para obtener la **suma total** de personas que solicitaron **X servicio** en la X fecha.

les dejo la query con la que he intentado:

```
    SELECT(case  when campain_id=1981 or 
campain_id=2099  or campain_id=2163 or campain_id=2107 
or campain_id=2129 or campain_id=2169 or campain_id=2171  
or campain_id=2107 then 1
                    
                      when campain_id=1982 or campain_id=2100 
                      or campain_id=2164 
                      or campain_id=2118 or campain_id=2172 then 2
                      
                      when campain_id=1983 or campain_id=2101 
                      or campain_id=2165 
                      or campain_id=2119 or campain_id=2173 then 3
                      
                      when campain_id=1984 or campain_id=2102 
                      or campain_id=2166 
                      or campain_id=2174 or campain_id=2120 then 4
                      
                      when campain_id=1999 
                      or campain_id=2167 then 5
                      
                      when campain_id=2000 then 6 
                      when campain_id=2005 then 7
                      when campain_id=2006 then 8
                      when campain_id=2010 then 9
            end) as "Cantidad de Personas", count(id)
            FROM missions mi 
            INNER JOIN campains c on mi.campain_id=c.id_campain
            WHERE id_campain in(
        2163,2099,1981,1982,2129,2171,2169,2107,
        2182,2100,2164,2118,2172,
        2101,1983,2165,2119,2173,
        2102,1984,1999,2166,2174,2120,
        2178,2167,)
        GROUP BY 1
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: En la comunidad no se suele ver con buenos ojos el que la gente entre demandando que se le haga su tarea. Para tener más éxito en tu pregunta y conseguir una respuesta, te aconsejo editar la pregunta y pegar como texto el código o consultas que hayas probado o intentado tú mismo y donde tienes las dudas o los errores. Un saludo

Comment: Muestra qué has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: Editado, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es obtener el primer número entero (de n dígitos entre dos espacios) que aparece en la cadena utilizando expresiones regulares de las siguientes maneras:

```
SELECT (regexp_match("NAME", '\s[\d]*\s'))[1] FROM tabla;

ó

SELECT (regexp_match("NAME", '\s[0-9]*\s'))[1] FROM tabla;

ó

SELECT (regexp_match("NAME", '\s[[:digit:]]*\s'))[1] FROM tabla;
```

Si conoces la ubicación exacta en la cadena podrías utilizar la función `substring()`. Depende del formato que tenga la misma.

Luego quitas los espacios con la función `trim()`, casteas el resultado a entero para sumarlos posteriormente:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(trim((regexp_match("NAME", '\s[\d]*\s'))[1]) AS integer))
FROM tabla;
```

#### Contestando a la pregunta en los comentarios:

Deberías poner el `CASE` dentro de la función `SUM()`.

```
SELECT SUM(
           CASE WHEN campain_id = 1936 OR campain_id=1901 OR campain_id = 1703 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE CAST(trim((regexp_match("NAME", '\s[\d]*\s'))[1]) AS integer) 
                END) AS "Cantidad de solicitudes"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! está respuesta me ayudó bastante, de hecho la apliqué para lo que quería, gracias por compartir tu ayuda, que tengas un buen día!

Comment: De nada @EduardoVergaraAlvarado! En ese caso no olvides indicar que mi repsuesta contestó tu pregunta, así la pregunta queda marcada como respondida.

Comment: Listo! @nachospiu, me quedó una duda, en la última condición, además de sumar el valor que contenga dicho número, una variable que no contenga número pero si valga '1' en la necesidad, cómo la validaría en dicha condición de sumar los valores que me indique el campo?  Por ejemplo: SELECT case when campain_id=1936 or campain_id=1901 or campain_id=1703 then '1'
else (SUM(CAST(trim((regexp_match(c.name, '\s[\d]*\s'))[1]) AS integer))) end as "Cantidad de solicitudes". En donde las campain_id 1936 y 1901 no contienen número en el campo, pero si valgan 1 y la función la considere y sume

Comment: @EduardoVergaraAlvarado en ese caso deberías poner el `CASE` dentro de la función `SUM()`, edité mi respuesta para que veas como quedaría.

Comment: No se bien que es lo que quieres hacer, pero también puedes utilizar un `CASE` en caso de que  "NAME" sea nulo y retornar 1 y sino buscar el valor en la cadena (el `CASE` dentro de `SUM()`).

Comment: Buenisimo! Muchas gracias de verdad que es muy útil tu respuesta

Comment: De nada @EduardoVergaraAlvarado, me alegra haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

A modo de ejemplo te pondré una consulta que sumaría los números encontrados en cadenas de texto

```
SELECT SUM(
    IF (
        --Con convert convertimos texto en número. 
        --En éste caso buscamos el número al principio de la cadena si es distinto a cero
        CONVERT(columna_a_buscar, SIGNED) != 0,
        columna_a_buscar,
    IF (
        --si el primer if no da resultado, entrará en el segundo
        --aquí buscará un número en la segunda parte de la cadena por medio del SubString a partir de la segunda posición, si no devuelve cero
        columna_a_buscar REGEXP('[0-9]'),
        CONVERT(SUBSTR(columna_a_buscar FROM 2) , SIGNED), 0
    )))
FROM tabla;
```

Pero claro, en tu cadena, después del número se encuentra de nuevo texto, por lo que tendrías que recurrir a una función. Aquí me perdía, por lo que busqué por internet y encontré ésta solución:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS extractNumber;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION extractNumber (cadena1 VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS INT(11)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
    DECLARE posicion, resultado, longitud INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cadena2 VARCHAR(255);
    SET longitud = LENGTH(cadena1);
    SET resultado = CONVERT(cadena1, SIGNED);

    IF resultado = 0 THEN
        IF cadena1 REGEXP('[0-9]') THEN
            SET posicion = 2;
            checkString:WHILE posicion <= longitud DO
            SET cadena2 = SUBSTR(cadena1 FROM posicion);
            IF CONVERT(cadena2, SIGNED) != 0 THEN
                SET resultado = CONVERT(cadena2, SIGNED);
                LEAVE checkString;
            END IF;
            SET posicion = posicion + 1;
            END WHILE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN resultado;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Estraída de la página: [Extraer valores de una cadena](https://rubenlacasa.es/2013/08/20/como-extraer-un-valor-numerico-de-una-cadena-en-una-consulta-mysql-mysql-tips/)